# Cron schedule to run at 11:55, 12:00 and 12:05

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to create a Cron schedule to run at 11:55, 12:00 and 12:05 and using follwing expression-

```
 0 0,5,55 11,12 ? * * *
```

However above given schedule run at 11:00, 11:05,  11:55, 12:00, 12:05, 12:55. Not sure what I have missed.

Comment: Not sure if you can in a single expression. I guess you need two expressions, one for 11:55 and one for 12:00 and 12:05 as most implementations don't support ranges from 55 to 05 (they turn it around (05-55) instead of splitting it (55-60 and 00-05).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 triggers to execute *YourJob.class*.

```java
    public class Scheduler extends GenericServlet {

        @Override
        public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
            super.init(config);
            try {
                // this is YOUR job
                JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(YourJob.class).build();
                Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder
                        .newTrigger()
                        .forJob(job)
                        .withSchedule(
                                CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(
                                        "0 55 11 ? * * *"
                                )
                        ).build();
                Trigger trigger2 = TriggerBuilder
                        .newTrigger()
                        .forJob(job)
                        .withSchedule(
                                CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(
                                        "0 0,5 12 ? * * *"
                                )
                        ).build();
                Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
                scheduler.start();
                // run at 11:55 every day
                scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger1);
                // run at 12:00 and 12:05 every day
                scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger2);
            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(Scheduler.class).error(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```